# how can I add a spinner in a category preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I need to add a spinner in my PreferenceCategory with a text on its right is there a way to do that? plus when I create a checkboxpreference the text is on the left  how can I make the text appear on the right?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use these built in controls you have to use them the way they are designed. Its also good because it fits the android design that users expect.

If you need to do something different, just make your own preference screen. Its just a list view with click handlers, not too hard to make on your own. Then you get the styling you want.

Comment: and how can i add a spinner in the preference screen @rharter

Comment: You can't add a 'spinner', per se.  The closes that you can get without just making your own preference screen is a list preference.